# Symfony2 and Doctrine - Undefined index

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, twig

I have a Symfony 2.4.x project.

In there, I have two entities that are mapped together: Conference and Paper.

Each conference has papers and with a specific conference, I would like to get the number of papers.

For that, in my conference entity, I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Paper", mappedBy="conference")
 */
protected $papers;
```

In the entity Paper I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Conference", inversedBy="papers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="conference_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $conference;
```

When I had this project on Symfony2.0, everything worked well, but now I migrated it in Symfony 2.4.x and I am getting the following error when trying to do:

```
count($conf->getPapers()); // In the controller
{{ conf.papers | length }} // In the twig template
```

Error:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: hash_key in /var/www/git/conference2.0-v2.4/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php line 121
```

EDIT: Here are the full classes of the two entities in pastebin:

- Paper: http://pastebin.com/Fv7m70VN
- Conference: http://pastebin.com/dbCsH7Nh

EDIT 2: Here are some news that I found by trying to solve the problem. Another classe is involved there: Submission.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/bkdRtjdq

In the class Submission, I have the primary key that is hash_key and not the id.

Comment: Can you provide the full classes of paper and conference?

Comment: @Flask, I added the full code in my question using pastebin. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @Craig, unfortunately not.

Comment: I had a similar error (ContextErrorException) only mine was thrown in the ObjectHydrator. I ended up fixing it by removing the "inversedBy" part of the annotation. Not sure why, but it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it could be caused by the plural case: paper**s**

Try this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Paper", mappedBy="conference")
 */
protected $paper;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I was trying to get entities with `ObjectManager` in `ManyToMany` realtionship:

```
$repository->findBy(
    array('members' = > $user)
);
```

My workaround was to write `find` method in `Repository` with DQL:

```
public function findByMember(User $member)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

    $qb->innerJoin('g.members', 'wg')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('wg', ':member'))
        ->setParameter('member', $member);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any cases where papers are 0?  The conf.papers variable may be null and you would need to check if it's null first before counting.
     {% if conf.papers is empty %}
        ...
     {% endif %}